# Appen dict in to another as value

Tags: python, dictionary

I start like this:

```
_data = {}
dict1 = {"count": "100", "description": "Chip Resistor", "value": "100k"}
dict2 = {"count": "30", "description": "Cap", "value": "10k"}
```

Is it possible to get an output like this:

```
_data = {"Key number 1 ": { "count": "100", "description": "Chip Resistor", "value": "100k"},
"Key number 2": { "count": "30", "description": "Cap", "value": "10k"}}
```

I don't have a idea how put this to dicts togheter, without to overwrite the each keys

Comment: What do you mean by ' without to overwrite the each keys'?

Comment: i tried with _data.update(), than i overwrite each value in dict1 with dict2 because of the same key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_data["key number 1"] = dict1
_data["key number 2"] = dict2
```